# Script doesn't work after page loaded from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I have a shopping website where the items and products are loaded from JSON.

The issue is that after the page loads the script doesn't work.

If the items are little bit late to load on the page, at this time the script doesn't recognize the item and then it doesn't work.

Can you help me out, please

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            button.innerHTML = "<span style='transform:none;'>Successfully added</span>";
            button.disabled=true
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you can just use the built in delegation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".addtocart", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).html("<span style='transform:none;'>Successfully added</span>");
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much its works, but I ain't know whats happened but need to click twice for the function works, please if you have any solution or idea about it please help me and thank you